# Youtube-dl error

Tags: youtube-dl

Tried using youtube-dl with many different types of youtube videos and I keep getting an "unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error" message:

```
>youtube-dl 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-eWAc1Knlw' -v

 [debug] youtube-dl version 2013.02.02
 [debug] Python version 2.7.3
 [debug] Proxy map: {}
 [youtube] Setting language
 [youtube] t-eWAc1Knlw: Downloading video webpage
 [youtube] t-eWAc1Knlw: Downloading video info webpage

ERROR: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/__main__.py", line 17, in <module>
youtube_dl.main()
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 512, in main
_real_main()
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 496, in _real_main
retcode = fd.download(all_urls)
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/FileDownloader.py", line 505, in download
videos = ie.extract(url)
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/InfoExtractors.py", line 93, in extract
return self._real_extract(url)
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/InfoExtractors.py", line 397, in _real_extract
self._downloader.trouble(u'ERROR: unable to download video info webpage: %s' % compat_str(err))
File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/FileDownloader.py", line 230, in trouble
tb_data = traceback.format_list(traceback.extract_stack())
```

I've updated youtube-dl to version 2013.02.02 (latest one), by running it with the --update option, but it still produces the same error.

Comment: It's way easier to track these issues in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues). This looks like a transient error, either by youtube or by your ISP.

Comment: I don't think this is transient, it's been like this for a while now.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with another ISP?

Answer (score 3):

Please reinstall youtube-dl

```
sudo curl https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2014.03.03/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

More info: http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Answer (score 1):

**try to reinstall your youtube-dl**

1.update first

```
sudo apt-get update
```

2.then remove existing youtube-dl

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
```

3.then re-install it

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

you should now able to download youtube video via youtube-dl again

Answer (score 0):

I tried your answer

```
sudo curl https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2014.03.03/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

and it when I try to download a video stop here and just sits

[youtube] B07iK9uh9qY: Downloading js player vfl4_saJa

I have tried a couple of different videos

UPDATE:

I ran

```
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -U
```

now it downloads the video again. Thanks for your help :)